# Lightweight text editor for spell check & grammar check offline in OS X

Tags: osx, text-editor, spell-checker, grammar

I keep using LibreOffice for just the spell & grammar check, earlier it was MS Word.

Is there an offline version for English language that is multi-platform?

Basically an app like Windows Notepad with spell & grammar check.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **CudaText** editor (cross-platform, open source).

It has plugin **Spell Checker**, it is Hunspell based.
Plugin shows menu items in Plugins menu.

Comment: That CudaText seems to be for programming languages only, and the question was about spell & grammar check for English language.

Answer (score 0):

Notes on the Mac has spelling and grammar checking. Most Mac apps have this. Goto the edit menu and there is a spelling and Grammar selection. You can turn these on by selecting options you want. I don't know how well these work. Since this seems to be a system wide option it works with Textedit too.

You can also get a free account with Grammarly. It runs in background but monitors everything you type.

Comment: This question requires an offline tool. Grammarly does not work offline: https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000091011-Can-I-use-Grammarly-offline-

Answer (score 0):

Use Grammarly as an add-on in your favorite text editor. Its recommendation engine is intelligent, updated, and linguistically good. It works on browsers too.

Grammarly website - https://www.grammarly.com/

You will get add-ons for various editors and browsers, like, MS Word and Chrome, on this website itself.

Comment: This question requires an offline tool. Grammarly does not work offline: https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000091011-Can-I-use-Grammarly-offline-

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit which comes with every installation on a Mac supports both spelling and grammar checking. It is very lightweight.

[image]